# cmake does not run the StepTargets of an external project

Tags: cmake

I am using cmake with some projects added via `ExternalProject_add` and when i add a target with

```
ExternalProject_Add_StepTargets(SubProject doc)
ExternalProject_Add_Step(SubProject doc)
```

I get a new target `SubProject-doc`, but when I build it, the `doc` target of `SubProject` is not executed.

The external projects are added like this:

```
ExternalProject_add(subproject
    SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/subproject
    BINARY_DIR ${subproject_DIR}
    CMAKE_ARGS ${CMAKE_ARGS}
    INSTALL_DIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install
    DEPENDS subproject2
)
```

Comment: "the `doc` *target* of `SubProject` is not executed." - More correctly it should be said as "the `doc` **step** of `Subproject` is not executed". But how do you know that the step isn't executed? Being defined with `ExternalProject_Add_Step(SubProject doc)`, the step *does nothing*.

Comment: Step or target ... i just want to run the "doc" action on the subproject. That it's not run is easy to see, because it does not generate docs ;-).

Answer (score 2):

There is no *implicit* relation between **steps** of `ExternalProject` and **targets** of the subproject it represents. CMake only knows how to generate some predefined steps, like "download", "configure", "build". For create other steps you need to explicitely specify commands for them:

```
ExternalProject_Add_Step(Subproject doc
    # Equivalent to 'make doc' but in platform-independent manner
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build . --target doc
    # Use automatically-replaced token for refer to binary dir
    WORKING_DIRECTORY <BINARY_DIR>
    # When requested, step is always run.
    # (It is 'make doc' behavior who should care to not generate 
    # documentation if it has already been generated.)
    ALWAYS 1
    # This step is not a part of normal build of external project.
    EXCLUDE_FROM_MAIN 1
    # However, this step requires some other steps to be performed
    DEPENDEES configure
    )
```

After that you may create a target in the main project, which will perform given step:

```
ExternalProject_Add_StepTargets(SubProject doc)
```

See more in `ExternalProject` module's [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/ExternalProject.html).

Comment: I needed to add ``-G "${CMAKE_GENERATOR}"`` to the cmake command. But i still have a problem with the working directory, i always get ``CUSTOMBUILD : CMake error : The source directory "D:/work/build/all/project/doc" does not exist.``, where the ``doc`` part seems to be generated by cmake.

Comment: Do you get this error only with `make SubProject-doc` or it is also triggered with `make SubProject`? Without veiwing corresponded call to `ExternalProject_Add()` it is difficult to resolve the error.

Comment: only SubProject-doc doesn't work. And sorry don't get confused above, 'project' (like in projection) is one of the subprojects.

Comment: Again, it is difficult to resolve the error without viewing the call to `ExternalProject_Add()`. Please, add corresponded code into the question post.

Comment: I added the ``ExternalProject_Add`` call to the question.

Comment: Well, so in the error message the directory is `${subproject_DIR}/doc` (`doc` subdirectory under `BINARY_DIR` of subproject), am I right? It looks strange that CMake interpret it as a *source directory*. What happens if you manually switch to subproject's `BINARY_DIR` and type `make doc`?

Comment: The strange thing is especially, where the string "doc" in the path comes from, even when all cmake variables have "docs" there. I cannot just use "make doc", as i have to work here with MSVC. The "doc" step in the references MSVC solution works as intended.

Comment: `The "doc" step in the references MSVC solution works as intended.` - You mean `doc` **target**, don't you? And what if you go into subproject's `BINARY_DIR` and type `cmake -G <MSVC-generator> --build . --target doc`? This should effectively build given target with MSVC. My answer works for me on Linux with `make`.

Comment: It has exactly the same error message as the steptarget: ``cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015" --build . --target doc``gives
``CMake Error: The source directory "D:/work/build/all/project/doc" does not exist.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.``

Comment: Hmm, may be on Windows CMake wants full path in `--build` option? (In my code replace `--build  .` with `--build <BINARY_DIR>`). Otherwise I am out of ideas how to make `cmake --build` to work.